Apache warnings and UnsafeAllow3F flag
We recently updated Apache and I am now seeing many warnings like this where Apache throws a 403 in response to encoded urls:
AH: Unsafe URL with %3f URL rewritten without UnsafeAllow3F, referer: http://www.google.com

And here is the access log entry:
156.59.61.233 [www.example.com] - - [22/Sep/2024:18:43:38 -0400] "GET /index.php%3Froute%3Dproduct/product/download%26product_id%3D2038496%26download_id%3D10131 HTTP/1.1" 403 4072 "http://www.google.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.104 Safari/537.36 Core/1.53.4882.400 QQBrowser/9.7.13059.400"

The IP looks like Singapore, and although the url is actually valid when decoded, I'm scratching my head wondering why it would have been referred from Google.
Is there any chance at all that this is legit traffic which actually originated from Google? Or are they just spoofing the referrer?
I'm trying to make a decision about whether or not to enable the UnsafeAllow3F flag in our host config since this is a new one to me. I don't see any particular harm in the endpoint they are attempting to reach but could use some perspective on why and how this kind of traffic is happening.
